# why we need COW bit, when reference bit is sufficient?

Tags: unix

Page daemon uses reference and copy on write bit in page table. when ref bit is greater than 1, cow bit is 1, when ref bit is 1 , cow bit is zero.

What I do not understand is that page daemon can conclude via only ref bit, that the page is shared, and there is restriction to modify it, or the page is not shared, and it can be modified. So what is the purpose of COW bit?

Comment: Memory mapped files can also be shared so COW is not the only thing that can result in higher than one reference count

Comment: so you mean that memory mapped files can be shared, and can be free on modifying?

Comment: they can be created from shared memory which can modified by several processes

Comment: so modification done by one process can be used for others? ref bit greater than 1, and COW bit is set?

Comment: the processes are all accessing the same memory so yes, ref bit is greater than one but COW is not set

Comment: yes))) it was typo. thank you.